Getting a dependency conflict with flutter
I cloned a git repository into android studio. It is code written with the flutter framework. I try to get the dependencies using flutter pub get. However I get an error:
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.4.3.

Because universal_ui 0.0.8 doesn't support null safety and no versions of universal_ui match >0.0.8 <0.1.0, universal_ui ^0.0.8 is forbidden.
So, because sixam_mart depends on universal_ui ^0.0.8, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 1


So the error is triggered because universal_ui 0.0.8 doesn't support null safety.
I even changed the lower bound of sdk in the pubspec.yaml file:
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <4.0.0'

But i still get the same error. I Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated. Happy coding :)

You would need to downgrade your flutter SDK in order to use that library

As you are using Dart 3 and above, universal_ui is not Dart 3 incompatible as mention at pub.dev , I suggest you find other package that can handle the same problem

the  universal_ui package is out of date, with no support and analysis issues
so i sugest you to search other package that can handle your requirements
even if you downgrade the project sdk version
the package itself does not  support
